# Compare 2 Postgres Boolean Rows/Entities

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, boolean, compare

I am trying to compare two rows of boolean values representing different settings.

Row 1 is the Settings required for a Shift.
Row 2 is the Settings that a particular Candidate has worked in.

I want to know how many Skills that are required for the Shift are NOT met by the Candidate. **i.e. If row 1 equals true & row 2 does not equals true.**

*Basic answer can be a single number representing the above. Bonus points for indicating which columns were counted.*

The SQL that produced the example Table below is:

```
SELECT
    c.id as cId, s.id as sId, sm.*
FROM
    aws.settings_matrices AS sm
    LEFT JOIN aws.shifts AS s ON s.settings_matrix_id = sm.id
    LEFT JOIN aws.candidates AS c ON c.settings_matrix_id = sm.id
WHERE
    s.id = '327fff17-3ef6-4589-7459-8deafe5d489a'
    OR c.id = '643dc500-46ah-400b-b456-018bbbee9593'
```

| cid | sid | id | general_ward | health_safety | nursing_home | care_home | mental_health | learning_disab | assisted_living | respite | acute | palliative_care | sensory_impair | paediatric | surgical_gen | surgical_orth | accident_emer | midwifery | covid_ward | icu_itu | hdu | ent | elderly | urology | created_at | modified_at | created_by | modified_by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 327fff17-3ef6-4589-7459-8deafe5d489a | 643dc500-46ah-400b-b456-018bbbee9593 | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | t | t | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | f | 2021-07-21 14:29:28.484948 | 2021-07-22 08:34:47.197 | default | example@example.com |
| 91d7e3dc-fce0-446f-8g7b-9c271cce2592 | NULL | d044298c-6f28-43d9-892j-8cb22e3ea89c | t | t | t | NULL | f | f | t | t | t | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2021-07-16 12:04:47.953 | NULL | example@example.com | NULL |

Comment: Edit our question and show sample data.  No one but you really knows what the data looks like.  A DB/SQL fiddle might help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , this is actual sample data. What more do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's pretty basic. It's a single entity called a settings_matrix. Two other entities (Shift & Candidate) store a foreign key to a specific settings_matrix. I am comparing them for a specified candidate and shift.

Comment: So basically you are trying to compare a set of "required" booleans, which would be in one row (row A), one bool per column, and you need to find out how many of the same column values in a second row (row B) are not also set to true where the same column is true in row A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure in which language you would want to run the comparisons and counts, but since you want to only count the `True` values in the second line if that corresponding value in the first line is also `True`, you can't just count both lines and display the difference.

The logic would have to be something like:

If you don't have to hard type

```
var requiredThings = ["thing1", "thing2", "etc"];
int missingThins = 0;
foreach (var thing in requiredThings)
  if (thing1[thing] && thing2[thing])
    missingThings++;
```

If you have to hard type, you will sadly need to go the long way, probably

```
int missingThings = 0;
if (row1.thing1 && row2.thing1) missingThings++;
if (row1.thing2 && row2.thing2) missingThings++;
```

Comment: Great and possible. But JS is slow with the stack I'm using. A SQL answer would be preferable.